# Search for a previous command with the prefix I just typed

Tags: bash, shell, command-history

We can use up and down arrow to navigate in command history.

In some IDEs, such as Matlab, if we input something and then press the arrow keys, we scroll among only the history commands starting with what we have input. That's really convenient, but in a shell terminal, this doesn't work.

Is there some way to gain a similar function in a shell terminal? And any other tips for improving efficiency in terminal use?

Comment: You could simply use a shell that provides such a feature, like `fish` ;)

Comment: @yoann you're assuming bash doesn't. It does, via readline, just not accessible by default.

Comment: @muru I'm aware of CTRL+R in bash, and egmont's answer provides a neat way to do it with Page Up/Page Down. Is there however a way to do so with the arrow keys?

Comment: @yoann check out http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76591/70524. Instead of `\e[5~` and `\e[6~`, use `\e[A`, `\e[B`.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

What you are looking for is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>.

Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and then type part of the command you want.  Bash will display the first matching command.  Keep typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and bash will cycle through previous matching commands.

To search backwards in the history, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> instead.  (If <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> doesn't work that way for you, that likely means that you need to disable  XON/XOFF flow control: to do that, run `stty -ixon`.)

This is documented under "Searching" in `man bash`.

Comment: **`Ctrl-Q`** to quit the frozen state, if you already hit **`Ctrl-S`** without turning off flow control first and got your terminal frozen.

Answer (score 56):

Place these in your `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\e[5~": history-search-backward
"\e[6~": history-search-forward
```

These make <kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Page Down</kbd> behave as you wish. (Some distributions have it already configured it for you.) I personally find these way more convenient than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or `history`.

Update: bash-5.2 / readline-8.2, released in Sep 2022, make these the default behavior. No more need to tamper with `inputrc` to set it up.

Comment: This is the most convenient way in all current answers. Could u plz give a little explanation on the working mechanism?

Comment: `~/.inputrc` or `/etc/inputrc` or the file referenced by the environment variable `$INPUTRC` is the line editing configuration file of all application using readline, including bash (your shell). It has certain built-in line editing capabilities, including these two: in bash's manual page search for one of these keywords to find out more. `\e[5~`/`\e[6~` are the escape sequences generated by the Page Up/Down keys in most of the terminal emulators; to see it, launch the `cat` command and then press these keys (the escape byte is represented in the terminal as `^[`, in inputrc as `\e`).

Comment: The example in your original question says that the Up / Down keys work this way in Matlab. It would be interesting to see what happened if you placed the sequence of Up and Down in inputrc and assign to this action; would it work correctly, or have nasty side effects as it conflicts with their default behavior. I don't know, I'd be happy to hear your findings if you experiment with this.

Comment: When I do `echo $INPUTRC` it is empty. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: You could define it if you wanted, but I don't see too much point in it. Probably the easiest is to go with `~/.inputrc`.

Comment: I personally prefer overriding up and down arrow to do this: `"\e[A": history-search-backward` and `"\e[B": history-search-forward`

Comment: (@sid I reverted your faulty edit. First, why would the syntax be different for mac? Obviously makes no sense. Second, .inputrc is readline's config file, it's syntax is not shell script syntax, it is not to be sourced. Maybe it is not configured to be read as a readline config file on a mac, but then choose a different filename, not one that does have a different syntax and different role on other systems. The bind command could go to .bashrc for example.)

Answer (score 14):

Besides ^r / ^s history i-search:

<kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> inserts the last "word" of the previous command at the cursor.  Repeat it to get the last word from older commands.  (But note that a trailing `&` counts as the last word for background commands).

This is super handy for `mkdir foo`,  `cd` alt-dot.  Even faster than up-arrow, ^a, alt-d (delete forward word), `cd`.

To get the 2nd-to-last word, use `esc` `-` `2` `alt+.` (i.e. use an emacs-style numeric argument to `alt+.`.  Negative counts in from the end, positive counts forward from the start.)  But this is usually more trouble than it's worth; at some point it's faster to reach for the mouse and copy/paste, or up-arrow and ^w / ^y part of it (see below).

---

If your terminal is set up nicely/properly, ctrl-left and ctrl-right will go backward/forward by words.  If not, hopefully at least alt-b and alt-f will do the same thing.

---

ctrl-/ is an undo.  You can use auto-repeat for deleting words much more efficiently if you can undo when you overshoot by a bit.

---

More powerful mixing/matching of commands comes from using the kill-ring, which works just like in Emacs.  ctrl-y to paste the last ctrl-w / ctrl-u / ctrl-backspace / alt-d.  alt-y to cycle through older killed text.

Multiple ctrl-w or whatever in a row make on kill-ring entry.  Use left and right arrow or something to break up the entry if you want to remove two things and only paste one later.

Combining all of these together, you can

- start typing a command
- ctrl-r to go back to an old command and grab part of it with control-w or similar.
- esc-r or `alt+r` to restore it to how it was before you deleted part of it.
- alt-`>` to go to the end of history (i.e. down-arrow all the way), to get back to the command you were in the middle of.

---

Other interactive-use tips:

Enable `shopt -s globstar`, so you can do `**/*.c` (recursive including the current dir).  Sometimes handy for interactive use, but usually `find -name '*.c' -exec foo {} +` is better.

If you write bash scripts, you'll find it handy to have `shopt -s extglob` enabled in your interactive shells, too.  You will *sometimes* find a use for stuff like `*.!(c|h)` to match files that don't end with .c or .h.

Find aliases you like for `ls -l`, `less`, and anything else you do a lot.  (`cp -i`, `mv -i`, and `rm -I` are nice.  Don't get in the habit of *depending* on them to do a selective rm.  GNU rm's -I asks once for all the args.)

I like `alias m=less` (m for "more").  I have `less` set up with <kbd>,</kbd> and <kbd>.</kbd> bound to previous / next file (`lesskey`).  The default is a multi-keypress sequence that can't be used with autorepeat.

---

I like to do everything inside GNU screen.  I find it easier to keep track of numbered screen-windows than a boatload of tabs in Konsole (or any other terminal emulator I've tried).  If you don't already know `screen`, learn tmux because it's newer and less crufty.

To get something like the functionality of opening a new shell with the same cwd as another shell, I use [a custom hook for cd/pushd/popd that lets me do `cds 8` to cd to whatever dir my shell in screen window 8 is using.](https://superuser.com/a/874575/20798)  This works even for shells outside of the screen session, as long as there's only one screen session.

Comment: Mine doesn't seem to be "properly configured". A lot of the shortcuts I see here don't work, I am using stock Terminal from Ubuntu 14.04. How can I configure it?

Comment: @JorgeeFG: I think it worked for me out of the box with `gnome-terminal` in Ubuntu 14.04, before I switched to KDE.  The relevant option is in your terminal settings, esc-prefix vs high-bit, and maybe some other settings.  Some of them don't work perfectly for me through ssh.  (e.g. ctrl left/right munge the escape-code for the arrow key, and I get `5D` appearing literally)

Answer (score 14):

Add the following lines to your `~/.inputrc`

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
```

This is similar to egmont's answer, but instead of using Page Up and Page Down, it uses the escape sequences for Arrow Up and Arrow Down. This way is much more convenient to use on a Mac.

Answer (score 10):

The means I usually use is to combine the `history` command with `grep`

IE:

```
history | grep <command im looking for>
```

That will display a numbered history of commands you have typed that contain that command, you can then use:

```
!<number listed in history command>
```

to redo that command.

IE:

`history | grep history`

```
142  history
143  history | grep lvresize
568  history | grep echo
570  history | grep echo
571  history | grep history
```

followed by:
`!571`

will repeat `history | grep history`

Comment: C-R = much better + much safer

Comment: Perhaps, Personally I find a history piped to grep to be a faster means of finding most commands. As far as Safer, I'm not sure what you mean, what are the inherent risks in using history as apposed to searching through it with c-R?

Comment: @Gravy I suspect PSkocik means the `!` history substitution is less safe.

Comment: fair enough, though i still have to restate the core of the question, I'm not sure what the inherent risks are of using `!` for recalling history is. I @derobert Along the same lines, having never really used `ctrl-r` in the past, i've tested it on 3 separate ssh sessions to various machines, ranging from Centos/Rhel to solaris, and after 1-2 command cycles it has frozen my terminal session each time, which isn't a promising outcome :\ Thoughts?

Comment: @Gravy The inherent risks would be accidentally getting the wrong line. No idea why your terminal has frozen, unless you used Control-S and you have xon/xoff flow control enabled (often the default). If so, Control-Q will bring it back.

Comment: @derobert Fair point. Control-S definitely not the issue. Will have to investigate. Thank you for the perspective.

Comment: Bash has an option for giving you the expanded line for review before executing it, which makes it somewhat less dangerous (think about running rm -rf * in the wrong directory because you got the number after ! wrong), but I think c-r is much more practical. Nothing wrong with grepping, though.

Comment: I agree with @PSkocik, c-r is *much* better because it's easier to edit the history line, rather than just run it again the same way.  Running the exact-same command again is a trivial case of what you can do to save time re-typing variations on complex one-liners, or tab-completing a different file in a long path.  See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

I always tend to configure my machines with an large **HISTSIZE** value so it keeps a longer history list, as well as **HISTTIMEFORMAT** with the time stamp value so I can see when was the command ran.

```
export HISTSIZE=10000
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%m/%d/%Y %T "
```

Answer (score 3):

I used daily these tips *(and some others)* in my bash terminal:

- **Execute last command:** `!!`
- **Print last command:** `!!:p` (*It's equal to press up arrow* [**↑**])
- **Execute command** *N* **from history:** `!N`
- **Print command** *N* **from history:** `!N:p`
- **Execute last command starting with** *prefix* **from history:** `!prefix`
- **Print last command starting with** *prefix* **from history:** `!prefix:p`

Comment: I think that using the command N from history is one of the greatest ever paths for shoot oneself in the foot for most humans :-) Just saying

Answer (score 2):

If it's okay for you to use `zsh` instead of `bash`, you can use *oh-mi-zsh* for that.

You can navigate your command history with the up and down arrows. It also allows the same navigation when you have already typed the text (as in Mathlab).

**edit:** Oh-my-zsh is a large, developer-oriented software package that includes many other features, e.g. aliases, themes, plugins. These extras make the distribution more complex to use than a keyboard shortcut.

https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh

Answer (score 1):

Add the following alias to ~/.bashrc

```
alias h='history | awk '"'"'{$1="";print}'"'"' |sed "s/^ *//" |grep -v "^h " | sort | uniq | grep'
```

Usage: `h fire` will get me a list of commands contain *fire*. or `h ^fire` will get me a list of commands begin with *fire*.

This is useful when I want to view a series of commands at the same time.

By the way, `'"'"'` is ugly but I couldn't find other ways to avoid single quotes in single quotes.

Comment: fyi -`h="history | awk '{\$1=\"\"; print}'` should work. alternatively create a function and call that.

Comment: thank you DarkHeart, but I tried your code, found not worked in my environment, maybe there is something different in mine