# How do I convert inputrc settings to bashrc ones?

Tags: bash, readline

I'd like to keep my modifications to as few files as possible, so I don't want to touch `.inputrc` unless I absolutely have to. So, given `.inputrc` lines [like](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/231632/70524):

```
"\e[5~": history-search-backward
"\e[6~": history-search-forward
```

How can I apply them only using `bash`?

[This SU post](https://superuser.com/a/419676/334516) indicated that `bind` could read from `.inputrc`, and `bind`'s help says:

```
$ help bind
bind: bind [-lpsvPSVX] [-m keymap] [-f filename] [-q name] [-u name] [-r keyseq] [-x keyseq:shell-command] [keyseq:readline-function or readline-command]
```

`history-search-*` look like readline functions, so I tried:

```
bind "\e[6~":history-search-forward
bind "\e[5~":history-search-backward
```

<kbd>Page Up</kbd> now triggers a bell, <kbd>Page Down</kbd> printed a `~`.

Is there a general way for me to use `inputrc` lines in `bash`?

Comment: One reason to use `.inputrc` here, though, is so that the key bindings are available in *any* program that uses `readline`, not just `bash`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to what I have in my `.bashrc` you need something like

```
bind '"\e[6~": history-search-forward'
```

Comment: ... and now I feel like an idiot. I stopped trying after `bind '\e[6~': history-search-forward` failed.

Comment: I think I had trouble getting there too, as I noted it as non-obvious in my personal "help on bash" file.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone else searching, this works for *all* `inputrc` commands: just wrap them in quotes, shove a `bind` in front, and you're good (make sure you have different types of quotes if the actual `inputrc` command itself requires quotes).

---

For example, an `inputrc` could have

```bsh
# makes tab-completion *immediately* return multiple options, 
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
# bind C-d to go forword, not crush the shell
"\C-d": shell-forward-word
```

To put those in your `bashrc`, it's just

```bsh
bind "set show-all-if-ambiguous on"
bind '"\C-d": shell-forward-word'
```