# How do I properly source .inputrc?

Tags: inputrc

I have several `set` commands in `.inputrc`. Previously I've loaded them via `source .inputrc`, but some programs are unhappy with `set` commands in `.profile`. What is the correct way of sourcing it?

Comment: Does this help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231726/how-do-i-convert-inputrc-settings-to-bashrc-ones

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't.

See the "INITIALIZATION FILE" section of the readline manual (`man readline`):

> Readline is customized by putting commands in an initialization file
>          (the inputrc file).  The name of this file is taken from  the  value
>          of the INPUTRC environment variable.  If that variable is unset, the
>          default is ~/.inputrc.  If that file  does not exist  or  cannot  be
>          read,  the  ultimate  default is /etc/inputrc.  **When a program which
>          uses the readline library starts up, the init file is read, and  the
>          key bindings and variables are set**.

Comment: Also `Ctrl-x Ctrl-r` is bound by default to `re-read-init-file` so it's not necessary to open new session of the program.