# Use Mac OS command key in bash's bind command

Tags: bash, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal.app

In my ubuntu bash, I had remapped `Ctrl-y` key combo to copy text to clipboard as,

```
bind -x '"\C-y": copy_line_from_x_clipboard'
```

It works. Now, I am migrating to Macbook, I like to use `Command` key instead of `Ctrl` key above. I am not seeing any keybinding examples on net that contain Mac OS' command key. 
And I tried to get the key combo for `Command-y` using the command `sed -n l` as explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76566/where-do-i-find-a-list-of-terminal-key-codes-to-remap-shortcuts-in-bash), but it shows empty line after taking `Command-y` key input.

For those who are interested, the callee function to paste text from clipboard is,

```
copy_line_from_x_clipboard() {
        local n=$READLINE_POINT
        local l=$READLINE_LINE
       local s=$(xsel -ob)
       READLINE_LINE=${l:0:$n}$s${l:$n:$((${#l}-n))}
       #READLINE_LINE=${l:0:$n}$s
       READLINE_POINT=$((n+${#s}))
}
```

Comment: Are you using Terminal.app or iTerm or `$other`? If so, is there anything in the preferences for those for pushing a command key into something that gets to the shell?

Comment: i use `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to one of the comments in *[Use CMD-mappings in console Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310077/use-cmd-mappings-in-console-vim)*, you cannot use the <kbd>Command</kbd> key in Terminal.app, though you *could* in iTerm2.

You're probably looking for *modifier*, like <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>control</kbd>, e.g., something analogous to the <kbd>alt</kbd> or <kbd>meta</kbd> key.

In Terminal.app's keyboard preferences, you have an initial set of key definitions which use these modifiers—along with <kbd>Option</kbd>.  You can alter these definitions, or add new ones.

Here are a couple of screenshots showing that dialog:

[image: showing the keyboard preferences screen]

The second screenshot shows <kbd>Option</kbd> (alone, or in combination with other modifiers), but <kbd>Command</kbd> is not available for use by programs running in the terminal:

[image: showing the available modifiers for keys]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a useful trick if you are using iTerm2...

1. go to preferences->keys->key bindings
2. set whatever key combo you want to customize to 'Ignore' to detach it from its default function
3. go to preferences->profile->keys
4. set your key combo to send the Unicode hex code for the ctrl- equivalent, for instance ^R is 0x12