# its possible to map "undo" to another combination?

Tags: bash, zsh, keyboard-shortcuts

`CTRL+_` is used to do UNDO in console; is it possible to map that another key combination like `CMD + Z`?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76566/where-do-i-find-a-list-of-terminal-key-codes-to-remap-shortcuts-in-bash#76591) discussion? Maybe it can be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but that depends on your shell. In **bash**, you have to use `bind`:

```
$ bind '\C-t':undo
```

This will bind <kbd>Ctrl-t</kbd> to `undo`. Note that you cannot bind <kbd>Ctrl-z</kbd> in most terminal emulators. Refer to `help bind` for more information.

If you want the current list of all key bindings, use `bind -P | grep -v "not found"`.

---

In **zsh**, you have to use [`bindkey`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Zle-Builtins):

```
$ bindkey '\C-t' undo
```

Keep in mind that you probably want to remove the old bindings for whatever key you'll choose. For example, `\C-t` is bound to `transpose-chars`.

In case you're wondering where all those combinations come from: Emacs. See `man 1 bash`, section "Readline Command Names" for more information.

Comment: You actually *can* bind `Ctrl-z` in `zsh`. Also, this does not depend on the terminal emulator, but on the shell. While a terminal emulator *might* prevent `Ctrl-z` from being used, I think it unlikely that any terminal emulator actually does do this, as this is shortcut is generally used to send `SIGSTOP` to the running process.

Comment: The "inability" to bind Ctrl+z or Ctrl+c is because the terminal intercepts these and sends signals *instead*, thus the shell does not see these characters. But if you bind Ctrl+z (or Ctrl+c) *and* reconfigure the terminal (e.g. `stty susp ^Y intr ^U`) then the binding(s) will work.

Comment: @Adaephon, that's `SIGTSTP` sent to the foreground process group / job, not *"`SIGSTOP` sent to the running process"*.