# Why does my binded key result in an extra tilde?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, escape-characters

I want to remap my <kbd>F9</kbd> key to the dollar sign (`$`) symbol.

So I ran this command

```
bind '"\e[20": "$"'
```

Now whenever I type the <kbd>F9</kbd> key, instead of getting just

```
$
```

I get

```
$~
```

Why is the extra tilde there and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: `F9` is `\e[20~` for me. That's probably where the `~` comes from. Press Ctrl-V and then F9. What do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
bind '"\e[20~": "$"'
```

To determine character sequence for a key press,

- Press <kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd>  and press the key for which you want to get the character sequence.

**Example:**

For key <kbd>F9</kbd>, I get `^[[20~` where `^[` is <kbd>Esc</kbd> key and remaining sequence is for <kbd>F9</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. For me Ctrl+v does not work but I was able to get the keycode using the method described [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76566/where-do-i-find-a-list-of-terminal-key-codes-to-remap-shortcuts-in-bash)