# AWS Session Manager SSH Web Client: How to use the Alt key for navigation?

Tags: bash, ssh, keyboard-shortcuts, aws

When connecting to an EC2 instance (Amazon Linux) via the AWS Systems Manager (SSM) session connect feature, I'm able to successfully connect to my instance using its SSH web client. Unfortunately, I am very used to using the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key for navigation in the shell (e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to move one word forward, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> to move one word backwards). The <kbd>Alt</kbd> key though doesn't work via that client, is there a way to configure it?

Currently when I input <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>, I get the following symbols, i.e. instead of moving the cursor before the wrongarg argument, it adds the extra two characters at the end:

[image]

Instead of moving a word back, I get what looks like an integral symbol from Calculus!

Comment: What shell is that? Is it actual `sh` or is it `bash` in POSIX mode or maybe something like `dash`? What is the output of `ps -p $$`?

Comment: It is using sh which is just a symbolic link to bash:
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: Yep that makes sense. When `bash` is called as `sh`, it is running in "POSIX mode" and the Alt keybindings don't seem to be enabled.

Comment: Interesting, although when I ran bash directly from the sh shell, the lack of Alt keybindings persisted.  Is there an easier way than what I came up with to enable support of the Alt keybindings?

Comment: You should be able to configure that in `~/.inputrc`. See `man 3 readline`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to this [StackExchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76566/where-do-i-find-a-list-of-terminal-key-codes-to-remap-shortcuts-in-bash) for providing the foundation for solving this.

Use the `sed` command to determine the key combination is sent to the terminal when the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> sequences are entered (after each key combo you press hit the enter key to get the code e.g. \306\222):

```
sed -n l
ƒ
\306\222$
∫
\342\210\253$
```

Note the `ƒ` and the `∫` are the symbols that are displayed in my terminal when I press the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> sequences respectively.  Now armed with the key combination that is sent (excluding the ending `$` character), I can use the following bash `bind`  commands to map to the desired behavior as shown below:

```
bind '"\306\222":forward-word'
bind '"\342\210\253":backward-word'
```

And now when I enter <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd>, bash moves one word forward and backwards.